# How can I capture PDFs of websites that faithfully reproduce styles and layout?

Tags: firefox, pdf, internet-explorer, adobe-acrobat

Working with a limited set-up (Adobe Acrobat X Pro, IE 7, Firefox 9) I need to create hundreds of PDF archives of websites. As much as possible I need to preserve the style and layout of the pages. I also need to remove certain page elements. Text must be preserved,

There are two methods I have tried:

#### Using Acrobat X Pro to capture pages

- **Pros:** The pages are captured very faithfully.
- **Cons:** The PDF editing tools are very limited so I am unable to make necessary modifications to the pages.

#### Using Firefox 9 to print as PDF

- **Pros:** I can use the *Hack the Web* and *Firebug* extensions to make all the page modifications I need.
- **Cons:** The resulting PDF lacks links and doesn't print the page as it appears on-screen.

Adobe do have an Acrobat extension for Firefox, but they haven't updated it lately. Them supporting their application would probably be my ideal solution, but I'm very interested to find alternative solutions!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an extra or an [alternative CSS stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/alternatives.en.html) that suppresses certain HTML elements ([display="none"](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)) before using Acrobat X Pro to convert to PDF?.

Comment: Thank you RedGrittyBrick! Actually the CSS is { display:none; }, but this absolutely does the job for me. As a bonus, I don't have to remove unwanted elements manually from every page.

Comment: Hm. Tragically, Acrobat seems to ignore my stylesheet, even though IE uses it. :/